# How to create a frequency table with Coordinates

Tags: r

Looking to create a frequency table to create an interactive map. I have the coordinates of the Starbucks in California and need to separate it by region, and I'm unsure how to do this

```
starbucks <- data.frame(longitude = c(-122.2761, -118.374, -118.2426),
latitude = c(37.77966, 33.97764, 34.05123))
```

How would I create a freq. table for this data separated by regions, so I can input into a leaflet interactive map?

Comment: Something like: `table(starbucks)`?

Comment: How does the regions data frame look like, can you give an example of that one as well?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example.  It proves all 3 are in CA.

```
library(sf)
library(tigris)
library(dplyr)
starbucks <- data.frame(longitude = c(-122.2761, -118.374, -118.2426),
                        latitude = c(37.77966, 33.97764, 34.05123))
states <- tigris::states()
aggregate(states, 
          sf::st_as_sf(starbucks, coords = c('longitude', 'latitude'), crs = st_crs(states)),
          I) %>%  
  as_tibble() %>% 
  select(NAME) %>% 
  table()

.
California 
         3
```